# Why Port Forwarding is not working in Huawei Router

Tags: portforwarding

I facing a problem in port forwarding for my Huawei HG8145V5 router. After doing the port mapping configuration at external port 80, while I am testing the open port forwarding, it is giving error that the port is closed for my public ip.

Let me explain why I am trying this step.

I have created a REST web service using SpringBoot and when I am accessing the API end point using localhost or my machine ip, it is working fine. But now I am trying access it publicly and that is why I am trying with this port forwarding option. But facing the issue as I mentioned.

Any help is much appreciated!! :)